# Creating objects depending on an Array

Tags: java, swing

I've got an Array holding the amount of directories located in an another directory. However my problem is I have to create a `JPanel` for each folder.

For example:

```
File folder = new File("...");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); <- this contains the folders ({"folder1","folder2","folder3",...}).
```

Now I don't know how to fix this.

Some code I have written:

```
SystemAPI sapi = new SystemAPI(); <- custom written API  
File folder = new File(sapi.getHomeDir+"\\Documents\\*programname*\\default");  
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    try{
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getName());
            } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(listOfFiles[i].getName());
            }
        }   
    }catch(Exception a){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Occurred", "Error Dialog", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: Can we see some code showing what you have done and how display the directories in your `JPanel`?

Comment: i removed my attempt because it just used the same panel

Comment: What are you storing and displaying your directory on? You could create a method which repeats the process. I will post an example in an answer below in a little

Comment: I am temporarily just printing it in the console, Is that you ment?

Comment: what are these JPanel objects for?  Do you want to display a file name in each panel?  what `Container` or `ContentPane` are you putting them in?  It will be hard to help you without a little more explanation and code.

Comment: I don't feel like you have described your problem well.  I understand your problem is you need to create a `JPanel` for each `File` in your array.  So, loop through your array, create a new JPanel and add it to a layout, and add labels or various swing components that display the file info the way you want it.   Not to sound condescending, but I suggest reading the tutorials here, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html they have a lot of helpful examples.

Comment: @JarnoGabriël I created a example GUI which displays any amount of directories and its files on one `JPanel`. You can change it to your own layout and requirements and if you want a lot of results you could use a `JScrollPane` so you can scroll through the directories

Comment: @JarnoGabriël I completely re worked my answer since my answer did not answer your question properly. It now creates different panels for each directory specified in the method `listFiles`

Comment: @JarnoGabriël I redid the code for you. It now does exactly what you asked. If you feel it doesn't, please let me know. Also if it does do exactly what you want I would be grateful if you accepted it as an answer using the tick next to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (I made it using a layout provided by `MigLayout` but that can be changed)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class SimpleGUI
{
    public JFrame myMainWindow = new JFrame("Multtiple directories");

    JPanel[] guiPanelS = new JPanel[1000];
    JScrollPane[] guiJSP = new JScrollPane[1000];
    public JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    int pI = 0;
    String mainDirectory = "C:/Users/Daniel/Dropbox/Programming/Code/Notepad++/Java/Stack Overflow";
    String mainDirectoryName = new File(mainDirectory).getName();
    int indentForMainPanel = 30;
    String parseIndent = Integer.toString(indentForMainPanel);
    String lastDirOpen = mainDirectory;
    String lastDirOpenBut = mainDirectory;
    ArrayList<File> directoriesList = new ArrayList<File>();

    public void runGUI()
    {
        myMainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        myMainWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        listFilesHD(new File(mainDirectory),mainDirectoryName);

        final boolean showTabsHeader = false;
        tabbedPane.setUI(new javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI()
        {
            @Override
            protected int calculateTabAreaHeight(int tabPlacement, int horizRunCount, int maxTabHeight)
            {
                if(showTabsHeader)
                {
                    return super.calculateTabAreaHeight(tabPlacement, horizRunCount, maxTabHeight);
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            protected void paintTabArea(Graphics g,int tabPlacement,int selectedIndex){}
        });

        myMainWindow.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);
        tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new CustomChangeListener());

        myMainWindow.setVisible(true);
        myMainWindow.setBounds(10,10,500,500);
    }

    public void listFilesHD(File f,String dName)
    {
        MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("wrap", "[grow]");
        guiPanelS[pI] = new JPanel(layout);
        guiJSP[pI] = new JScrollPane(guiPanelS[pI]);
        JLabel currentDir = new JLabel("Current Directory: "+dName);
        guiPanelS[pI].add(currentDir,"align center");
        JLabel DirectoryName = new JLabel(dName);
        DirectoryName.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        guiPanelS[pI].add(DirectoryName);
        File[] listOfFiles = f.listFiles();

        JLabel[] listsValues = new JLabel[listOfFiles.length];
        JButton[] tabSwitch = new JButton[listOfFiles.length];

        int i=0;
        int i2=0;
        for(File fileTemp:listOfFiles)
        {
            listsValues[i] = new JLabel(listOfFiles[i].getName());
            if(listOfFiles[i].isDirectory())
            {
                directoriesList.add(listOfFiles[i]);
                tabSwitch[i2] = new JButton(listOfFiles[i].getName());
                tabSwitch[i2].setOpaque(false); //These remove the button filling and border
                tabSwitch[i2].setContentAreaFilled(false);
                tabSwitch[i2].setBorder(null);
                tabSwitch[i2].setFocusable(false);
                tabSwitch[i2].setForeground(Color.RED);
                tabSwitch[i2].addActionListener(new openNewPaneActionListener());
                guiPanelS[pI].add(tabSwitch[i2],"gapLeft 30");
                i2++;
            }
            else if(listOfFiles[i].isFile())
            {
                guiPanelS[pI].add(listsValues[i],"gapLeft 30");
            }

            i++;
        }

        tabbedPane.addTab(f.getAbsolutePath(),guiJSP[pI]);
        guiJSP[pI].getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);
        pI++;
    }

    public void listFilesSubD(File f,String dName,String dPath, String homeDirectory)
    {
        MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("wrap", "[grow]");
        guiPanelS[pI] = new JPanel(layout);
        guiJSP[pI] = new JScrollPane(guiPanelS[pI]);
        JLabel currentDir = new JLabel("Current Directory: "+dName);
        guiPanelS[pI].add(currentDir,"align center");
        JButton homeDirectoryName = new JButton(homeDirectory);
        homeDirectoryName.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        homeDirectoryName.addActionListener(new backListener());
        homeDirectoryName.setOpaque(false); //These remove the button filling and border
        homeDirectoryName.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        homeDirectoryName.setBorder(null);
        homeDirectoryName.setFocusable(false);
        guiPanelS[pI].add(homeDirectoryName);

        if(!new File(lastDirOpenBut).getName().equals(mainDirectoryName))
        {
            JButton lastDirectoryName = new JButton(new File(lastDirOpenBut).getName());
            lastDirectoryName.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            lastDirectoryName.addActionListener(new upOneListener());
            lastDirectoryName.setOpaque(false);
            lastDirectoryName.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            lastDirectoryName.setBorder(null);
            lastDirectoryName.setFocusable(false);
            guiPanelS[pI].add(lastDirectoryName,"gapLeft 30");

            File[] listOfFiles = f.listFiles();

            JLabel[] listsValues = new JLabel[listOfFiles.length];
            JButton[] tabSwitch = new JButton[listOfFiles.length];

            int i=0;
            int i2=0;
            for(File fileTemp:listOfFiles)
            {
                listsValues[i] = new JLabel(listOfFiles[i].getName());
                if(listOfFiles[i].isDirectory())
                {
                    directoriesList.add(listOfFiles[i]);
                    tabSwitch[i2] = new JButton(listOfFiles[i].getName());
                    tabSwitch[i2].setOpaque(false);
                    tabSwitch[i2].setContentAreaFilled(false);
                    tabSwitch[i2].setBorder(null);
                    tabSwitch[i2].setFocusable(false);
                    tabSwitch[i2].setForeground(Color.RED);
                    tabSwitch[i2].addActionListener(new openNewPaneActionListener());
                    guiPanelS[pI].add(tabSwitch[i2],"gapLeft 60");
                    i2++;
                }
                else if(listOfFiles[i].isFile())
                {
                    guiPanelS[pI].add(listsValues[i],"gapLeft 60");
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            File[] listOfFiles = f.listFiles();

            JLabel[] listsValues = new JLabel[listOfFiles.length];
            JButton[] tabSwitch = new JButton[listOfFiles.length];

            int i=0;
            int i2=0;
            for(File fileTemp:listOfFiles)
            {
                listsValues[i] = new JLabel(listOfFiles[i].getName());
                if(listOfFiles[i].isDirectory())
                {
                    directoriesList.add(listOfFiles[i]);
                    tabSwitch[i2] = new JButton(listOfFiles[i].getName());
                    tabSwitch[i2].setOpaque(false); //These remove the button filling and border
                    tabSwitch[i2].setContentAreaFilled(false);
                    tabSwitch[i2].setBorder(null);
                    tabSwitch[i2].setFocusable(false);
                    tabSwitch[i2].setForeground(Color.RED);
                    tabSwitch[i2].addActionListener(new openNewPaneActionListener());
                    guiPanelS[pI].add(tabSwitch[i2],"gapLeft 30");
                    i2++;
                }
                else if(listOfFiles[i].isFile())
                {
                    guiPanelS[pI].add(listsValues[i],"gapLeft 30");
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

        if(tabbedPane.indexOfTab(dPath)==-1)
        {
            tabbedPane.addTab(dPath,guiJSP[pI]);
        }

        guiJSP[pI].getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);
        pI++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SimpleGUI sG = new SimpleGUI();
        sG.runGUI();
    }

    class openNewPaneActionListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            lastDirOpenBut = tabbedPane.getTitleAt(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex());
            String butSrcTxt = "";
            Object source = e.getSource();
            if (source instanceof JButton) 
            {
                JButton btn = (JButton)source;
                butSrcTxt = btn.getText();
            }

            boolean tF = false;
            File fMain = new File("");
            for(File f:directoriesList)
            {
                if(f.getName().equals(butSrcTxt))
                {
                    fMain = f;
                    tF = true;
                }
            }

            if(tF)
            {
                if(tabbedPane.indexOfTab(fMain.getAbsolutePath())==-1)
                {
                    listFilesSubD(fMain, butSrcTxt, fMain.getAbsolutePath(),mainDirectoryName);
                }

                tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(tabbedPane.indexOfTab(fMain.getAbsolutePath()));
            }

        }
    }

    class upOneListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(tabbedPane.indexOfTab(lastDirOpen));
        }
    }

    class CustomChangeListener implements ChangeListener
    {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
        {
            lastDirOpen = tabbedPane.getTitleAt(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex());
            int endIndex = lastDirOpen.lastIndexOf(Character.toString((char) 92));
            if (endIndex != -1)
            {
                lastDirOpen = lastDirOpen.substring(0, endIndex);
            }
        }
    }

    class backListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(0);
        }
    } 
}
```

The code produces a simple GUI (as shown in the picture below). The picture shows the directory currently open. The blue button is the home directory which opens when clicked. The files in the open directory are black. The sub directories are red buttons which when clicked open a new panel with the contents of that directory and finally the green button is the directory above the one currently open. For example if you are in `C:\\D\B` when the green button is clicked you would enter `C:\\D`.

All the panels are on a `JScrollPane` so you do not need to worry about the amount of files in the directory. You can now adapt this code to your own. I would also suggest you get `MigLayout` if you don't have it already so you can see how this little program works.

[image: Pic of compiled code]

Comment: Let me describe it better for you, I've got my `JFrame` and I've also got a directory with other directories in. Now I can't seem to figure out how to add those `JPanels` to the `JFrame`, In every `JPanel` there also has to be the name of the directory found insde the main directory.

Comment: @JarnoGabriël I see what you mean. I am at work currently but will change the code again when I get back to implement the changes.

Comment: Thank you, and i like the `JScrollPane` idea did't think of that yet.

Comment: @JarnoGabriël would you like the subdirectories of the subdirectories opened in the same panel as the subdirectory or in different panels again?

Comment: I would like them in different `JPanels`

Comment: @JarnoGabriël No Problem